# Проект написаний на java 8 не работает корректно на java 11

Tags: java, java-11

Когда я запускаю свой проект на java 11 виводит совсем не то что должно.
Результат компиляции:

```
------Crypto Historical Data---------------
[Client] Connected to server m.islb.one:30000!
{"FrameworkVersion":null,"PacketCompressors":["GZipPacketCompressor"],"PacketEncryptors":null,"PacketSerializers":["MsgPackSerializer","JsonPacketSerializer"]}
```

Пробежался дебагером, нашол такое:

```
library source does not match the bytecode for class Reflection ,
```

как на фото
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но на java 8 такое ж сообщение но проект работает корректно.

Сам `Reflection` используется для заполнения `Set` а потом и `HashMap` класами которие мечение спец. метками.

```
  private static void LoadPlatformPacketTypesFromAssembly() {
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections();

    Set<Class<? extends Object>> allProtocolMessages =
            reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(IntenseLabPacket.class);

    allProtocolMessages.forEach(aClass -> {
        crc32.reset();
        crc32.update(aClass.getSimpleName().getBytes());
        messageTypesMap.put(aClass, (int) crc32.getValue());

    });

}
```

Вместо заполнения, функция видает `size = 0`.
Мой pom файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>JLabFramework</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.msgpack</groupId>
        <artifactId>msgpack-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
        <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.msgpack</groupId>
        <artifactId>msgpack</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.12</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
                <outputDirectory>D:\iLabTrading\API JAVA\iLabTrading-Java-API\out</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Замените изображения текстом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в строчке:

```
 Reflections reflections = new Reflections();
```

Дело в том, что, насколько я понял, `java 1.8` не требует указания конкретного `path` где лежат нашы "мечение" класы в отличии от `java 9..11`.
Решение следующее:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("way to path where our classes");
```